# How meteor handles files with same name but different paths

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor project, Can I have app/client/abc.js AND app/server/abc.js and expect meteor to handle them graciously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have abc.js in both client and server folders. However, /client/abc.js will be loaded only on client, whereas /server/abc.js will be loaded only on server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. File names in meteor are not currently meaningful apart from manipulating load order. See the [structuring your app](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) section of the docs.